# How addition and subtraction of integers rates

Tags: php

Looking script for addition and subtraction of integers rates? help

```
example:
0.50 - 50% = 0.25
35.52 - 47% = ....
```

Comment: you will have to remove the % and then just use basic math. 0.5-(0.5*0.5)

Comment: 0.50 - 0.50 = 0  I do not want this

Comment: 0.50 - 50% = 0.25 ====== 0.5-(0.5*0.5)

Comment: Have a closer look at Dagon's comment: 0.5-(0.5*0.5) = 0.5-(0.25) = 0.25

Comment: any way there is no actual php in your question

Comment: @Dagon Yes - but question actually is language independent (could have been C as well), so tags possibly should have been rather math or algorithm...

Comment: Well then its just basic math

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even it is very easy with this code

```
<?php
function abc($a,$b){
return $a*($b/100);
}

echo 10 - abc(10,50);//number,percent

echo 10 + abc(10,50);//number,percent    

?>
```

https://eval.in/566981

Answer (score 0):

Parse your percentages to numerical values:

```
  0% = 0.0
 50% = 5.0
100% = 1.0
  x% = x/100.0

y +/- x% = y * (1.0 +/- x/100.0)
```